# Error: -no applicable method for 'svm' applied to an object of class "formula"-

Tags: r, svm

Ok, I am new at machine learning and R, but this still looks crazy, because it's something I did 2 weeks ago and was working, and now it doesn't.
I was classifying some data with SVM.
I have a dataset to train and one to test, and used this simple code:

```
library("e1071")
train <- read.csv("train.csv", header=TRUE)
test <- read.csv("test.csv", header=TRUE)
svm.model <- svm(Gas ~ ., data = train, cost = 100, gamma = 1)
```

Here I got the error: --

> Error in UseMethod("svm") : no applicable method for 'svm' applied to
>   an object of class "formula"

--

I swear it was working well 2-3 weeks ago, and then I didn'... the only thing I did was installing ALSO R3.5.0, because some libraries were not working with 3.2.0 version.
But this is all in R3.2.0

I didn't put any data because it doesn't work even with iris dataset and Species instead of Gas.
I hope not to disturb too much, and that some kind soul can help.

Nym

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could directly call the svm function with the package name, like: "package_name::svm". It might have happened, that the function name got masked by another package.